# Anonymous access to paid downloads using unique link

Tags: commerce, uri, files, users

Is anyone aware of a solution using Drupal Commerce (or alternatives) whereby I can have a product which can go through the following sequence:

1. anonymous user places in cart
2. anonymous user goes to checkout
3. payment is completed
4. a unique token/string is assigned to the email address provided in purchase
5. a url from which an anonymous user can download the purchased file is created and emailed to the address provided as well as displayed on checkout completion screen
6. after a defined period of time the link would expire
7. non-expired links could then be retrieved via a form by supplying email address to resend them

I can achieve most of the above with commerce_file but it seems that it requires logging in to the user account to access paid for downloads.

Seems like this would be a use case that would not be completely unique so hoping someone has an idea of how best to achieve this without having to roll my own solution.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Drupal commerce has a permission to complete the checkout process, that might be your issue there, check the permissions page (admin/people/permissions) and grant anonymous users the "access checkout" permission

[image]

Comment: This allows anonymous users to complete the checkout process but doesn't solve the problem of accessing the purchased file after completing the payment unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using commerce file 2.x with commerce license? check out https://www.drupal.org/node/1395488 and docs in https://www.drupal.org/node/2043917

Comment: Ok so I now get a link on the checkout complete page that allows the downloading of the file. Just need to work out how to have that link sent to the user in an email and remain valid for the duration of the licence... if that's possible

Comment: You've got rule events on checkout complete that can trigger emails, adding the link in there I guess can be accomplished by tokens. You can user commerce_bily to generate an invoice in case you want that too.

Comment: The checkout provided link only works for that session, I'm not sure of the exact mechanism by which this works but is looking increasingly like there is no clean solution for what I was hoping to be able to do.

Comment: You need to build custom parts, yes, but that doesn't mean is not a clean solution. I guess it depends on how you validate whether the token is valid or not, right? I'm afraid that from this distance (:)) I won't be able to help further.